# How can I generate and store pages with unique URLs with servlets?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, web-development-server

I am just learning about servlets and Tomcat. I am trying to make a simple cart application that presents users with a list of things to buy then submit their order to the server, which will generate and store a web page on the server with a unique url that shows what they ordered.

I don't really know where to begin on this, as I have no idea how to generate the unique web page. I can only make a servlet named show-order which will cause the page to redirect to a static url (i.e localhost/cart/show-order) that will change every time a new order is placed. I would like to be able to view all past orders via unique URLs.

I have read about a method called encodeURL() which will return a unique URL if cookies are disabled, but I don't care about cookies, I want to always return unique URLs for the orders...

So to summarize: I can't figure out how to write a servlet which will produce multiple unique web pages and store them on the server for future viewing.

Comment: You need a url rewriting filter that maps urls like `/cart/order/8934/`  to internally access `/cart/show-order/?ordernum=3934` so you can read the ordernum as a parameter in your servlet with request.getParameter, then you pull the order from a *database*

Comment: Could you elaborate a little for me? Do i write the rewriting filter myself? And I still dont know how to generate a unique url with a servlet, I can only ever get cart/show-order to come up

Comment: There are a few that already exist. The most popular seems to be  tuckey-urlrewrite-filter (which has its own tag here on SO): http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/

Comment: My own question here might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22696504/url-rewrite-is-forwarding-rather-than-rewriting-in-backend