# Url Rewrite is redirecting rather than rewriting in backend

Tags: tomcat, url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I thought that tuckey-urlrewrite-filter would rewrite the URL in the backend.  So like if I typed in the address bar `http://localhost:8080/TEST/some/yo` I expect that address to stay in the address bar but in the backend for Tomcat to process it as if I had typed `http://localhost:8080/TEST/jspinwebinftest/?param=yo`  But instead its redirecting to `http://localhost:8080/TEST/jspinwebinftest/?param=yo` and showing that in address bar.

How can I get it to only rewrite the URL in the backend?  Here is my urlrewrite.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE urlrewrite
    PUBLIC "-//tuckey.org//DTD UrlRewrite 4.0//EN"
    "http://www.tuckey.org/res/dtds/urlrewrite4.0.dtd">
<urlrewrite>
    <rule>
       <from>^/some/(.*)$</from>
       <to type="redirect">/TEST/jspinwebinftest/?param=$1</to>
    </rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. Pretty simple actually.  I needed to remove the `type="redirect"` that was on the example XML at the tuckey website.  And I found that when redirecting, you have to add your context app in the `to` tag, but when not redirecting, you should not:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE urlrewrite
    PUBLIC "-//tuckey.org//DTD UrlRewrite 4.0//EN"
    "http://www.tuckey.org/res/dtds/urlrewrite4.0.dtd">
<urlrewrite>
    <rule>
       <from>^/some/(.*)$</from>
       <to>/jspinwebinftest/?param=$1</to>
    </rule>
</urlrewrite>
```