# JAVA/JSP clean urls by content choosing from database

Tags: java, database, jsp, url-rewriting

I've asked a question before about clean urls in java/jsp website and I got answer of it that I will need to configure my web.xml file like this

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>yourjsp</servlet-name>
<jsp-file>/yourjsp.jsp</jsp-file> // here you can give jsp location
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>yourjsp</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/yourjsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

So my question is that do I really have to map every URL or pattern in web.xml file?

What If I am developing a website which has USERs (NOT A SOCIAL NETWORK for GOD'S SAKE) but some type of community/forum system then I would like to use domain/UERnAME or domain/QUESTION or domain/question/what-ever-your-question-is etc, so any suggestion for that? And I want to clarify that I am still learning JAVA/JSP development and I'd like to learn it at beginner level of me.

Thank you all for helping me.

Comment: I would use some web framework that handles it nicely, for example spring-mvc which gives you pretty url end point for each controller separately makes it much easy to manage your urls

Comment: Thats good option for me. Thanks for that, but if I don't want to use any framework than is there any option? Just for my knowledge.

Comment: Look into Tuckey URLRewrite. Its much more powerful than web.xml due to using Regex for the rules and it allows you to use path parts as parameters. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22696504/url-rewrite-is-redirecting-rather-than-rewriting-in-backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Servlet 3.0, you don't need to use the web.xml file to map the URL to the desired resource/page.

You can do something like this:

```
@WebServlet("/UserController")
public class UserController extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
        IOException {
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/test.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

Where the URL would be `http://your-domain/UserController`

You can read a bit more about it here: http://java.dzone.com/articles/checking-out-what-new-servlet